# Android Sticky Service Stops Sending HTTP Requests

Tags: android

I'm writing an Android app whose main Activity starts a Service that makes itself sticky.  The Service makes repeated HTTP POSTs to a server, exchanging some information.  This process works perfectly as long as the phone's screen is on, but once I turn the screen off, the service stops after a while.  Is there any way to guarantee that my Service keeps running indefinitely?

Comment: It sounds like there is something wrong with your code. Have you seen an exception on logcat? Or are you catching Exceptions on the code that does the http request and not logging the error? For me, it sounds like your app is trying to refresh something on the activity, but the activity has been destroyed rathen than paused, and then the service fails. I'm saying this because the only reason why any of the services I coded "stopped" working, was that something threw an exception I didn't catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to guarantee that my Service keeps running indefinitely?

No.

Furthermore, you should not want your service to be "running indefinitely". Certainly your users do not want your service "running indefinitely", as that is why they will attack you with task killers, the force-stop operation in Manage Services in Settings, and so on. Not to mention all the lovely one-star ratings on the Market, choice comments in discussion boards, and the like that such applications will trigger.

Moreover, your problem here is not that your service is not running, per se, but that the device is falling asleep. This is perfectly normal. Users *want* their device to fall asleep -- otherwise, their battery life will be horrific.

> The Service makes repeated HTTP POSTs to a server, exchanging some information.

The proper way to do this is to use `AlarmManager`, to trigger your code to execute periodically. Your user should be able to control the period (perhaps via a `SharedPreference`), including an option of "I'll manually request the data transfer, thanks". And, via an `IntentService` or similar means, you arrange for your code to be *started* by `AlarmManager`, do its work, *and then shut down to get out of RAM*.

Getting `AlarmManager` to wake up the device out of sleep mode is not that difficult (use a `_WAKEUP` flavor of alarm), but keeping the device awake long enough for you to do your HTTP request can be. The HTTP request cannot be performed on the main application thread, as it may take too long. One recipe is to use my [`WakefulIntentService` component](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful), which is an `IntentService` that keeps the device awake long enough for your work to be complete, then shuts down and allows the device to fall back asleep.

Answer (score 0):

**First Way:** What you can also do to make HTTP POSTS to a server continuously is, you can make a timer and inside the task of the timer ie. in run() of class TimerTask you can make startService() and as soon as you are done with the HTTP POST work you destroy the service. Thus on a periodic basis, the timer will start the service and there won't be any background service.

**Second:** You can also use the [PowerManager.WakeLock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html)

**Third:** You can use AlarmManager as discussed in the previous answer.